# Why is this javascript string match call return only one result?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

The code below is supposed to return 5 matches, but it only returns one.

```
    var str = '"<div id="rxAntMER" class="LEDPill" data-hookableby="globalid" data-oncolor="green" data-offcolor="maroon" data-paramname="rxAntMER" data-index="9" data-blockindex="0"></div>
<div id="rxAntMER" class="LEDPill" data-hookableby="globalid" data-oncolor="green" data-offcolor="maroon" data-paramname="rxAntMER" data-index="8" data-blockindex="0"></div><div id="rxAntMER" class="LEDPill" data-hookableby="globalid" data-oncolor="green" data-offcolor="maroon" data-paramname="rxAntMER" data-index="7" data-blockindex="0"></div>
<div id="rxAntMER" class="LEDPill" data-hookableby="globalid" data-oncolor="green" data-offcolor="maroon" data-paramname="rxAntMER" data-index="6" data-blockindex="0"></div><div id="rxAntMER" class="LEDPill" data-hookableby="globalid" data-oncolor="yellow" data-offcolor="maroon" data-paramname="rxAntMER" data-index="5" data-blockindex="0"></div>
<div id="rxAntMER" class="LEDPill" data-hookableby="globalid" data-oncolor="yellow" data-offcolor="maroon"';
       var results  = str.match(/id="rxAntMER".+data-blockindex="0"/g);
       alert("Number of matches = " + results.length);
```

The regex is trying to accomplish the following:

1. match literal 'id="rxAntMER"'
2. Followed by 1 or many 'any characters'
3. until matching literal 'data-blockindex="0"'

There are 5 such matches in the provided text.  I've tried samples, tutorials, and many permutations using RegEx(...) and string.Match(...), but I can't get the results I'm looking for.

Any suggestions or ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `id`s must be unique. [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630).

Comment: Convert to non-greedy, change this part in the regex `.+?` or to `[\S\s]+?`

Comment: @Oriol, When id's aren't unique, you just have to make sure that the id plus another attribute in the element make for a "unique" combination.  The text presented above is not a scrapping of HTML, it's an intermediary step to create proper HTML for my purposes (too long to explain). Suffice to say that it's not a typical scenario found in the wild, but something I created that requires several steps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` is greedy. As a reduced example, suppose you wanted to find how many angle-bracket pairs there were in `<1><2>`. You search with the regular expression `<.+>`, expecting it to match both. But wait, `.+` matches `1><2`, so you have one match.

You need to make `+` less greedy. Do that by following it with a `?`, so you have `.+?`.

Comment: Sorry for taking long to accept, the holidays got in the way.  One question regarding the greediness of "+", why does the addition of '\sdata-blockindex="0"' in my original pattern not stop "+" from continuing to match "any character"?

Comment: @fuzzlog: Because by nature of its being greedy, it doesn’t stop as soon as it can. You can think of the regular expression as trying both possibilities simultaneously: continue the `+`, or try to match the part after the `+`. Even after the second possibility succeeds, it still goes on trying the first possibility (extending the `+`), and eventually that one will succeed. It then has a few possible valid matches to choose from, and because `+` is greedy, it chooses the one with the longest match.